# Is the any advantage of putting CURRENT_TIMESTAMP into a sub select

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Would the first query be more performant than the second one?
And if so is there a better way to "join in the timestamp" than 1=1

```
SELECT s.StudentId, count(*) as SchoolCount 
FROM Student as s
 JOIN (SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as CURR_DTM) AS DTM ON 1 = 1
 JOIN StudentSchool ss
    ON ss.StudentId = s.StudentId
    AND (ss.StartDtm < CURR_DTM)
    AND (ss.EndDtm IS NULL OR ss.EndDtm > CURR_DTM)
GROUP BY s.StudentId

SELECT s.StudentId, count(*) as SchoolCount 
FROM Student as s
 JOIN StudentSchool ss
    ON ss.StudentId = s.StudentId
    AND (ss.StartDtm < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
    AND (ss.EndDtm IS NULL OR ss.EndDtm > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY s.StudentId
```

No sure how to analyze this in SSMS. Gave me the same results for both.

Comment: Did you compare the execution plans? In SSMS add both queries to the same window and hit Ctrl+L. SSMS will display the expected execution plan and the relative cost. I suspect the first will be the same or slower than the second, unless the query optimizer is smart enough to simplify the first into the second

Comment: Why is `JOIN (SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as CURR_DTM) AS DTM ON 1 = 1` used anyway? This is a rather unusual way of converting a constant into a table with no index or statistics. A row value constructor would be clearer but no better as far as performance is concerned

Comment: Yes. In my dev DB the results are the same. I guess there will only really be a difference with much more data. But the question in more from a theoretical point of view. I was wondering whether sqlsever would optimize the many calls to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP so that the second select would be fine.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That just me being an armature :) How would the select look using a row value constructor?

Comment: Theoretical questions can be solved by looking at the execution plan. That's the actual query that will get executed. `the second select would be fine.` the second *is* fine. It's the first that has problems. Instead of filtering on a known value, the first query creates a table that has no indexes, no statistics, which means the optimizer can't know what strategy to use unless it detects that this is just a constant and simplifies the first query into the second.

Comment: If you check the execution plans, especially if `StartDtm` and `EndDtm` are indexed, you'll see that the first query was converted into the second *and* `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is treated as a constant filter value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when a deterministic function is used several times in a query it is executed only once and associated with a variable which replaces the call of the function everywhere in the code where it is present.

The rand(), CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, GETDATE(), SYSDATETIME()... functions themselves have the same behavior.

Notable exception: NEWID()

The writer of the query seems to think that the value of the two calls of the function CURRENT_TIMESTAMP could have different values which is false...

Comment: Thanks @SQLpro exactly the info I was looking for. May I indulge you in a follow up question? What if I were to replace CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with my own stored procedure (that returns GETDATE with an offset ... for auto testing). Would the stored proc still only be called once?